# How to set desktop background color for all users for domain Windows machines?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, desktop

I have some Windows Server machines joined to a Active Directory domain. How can I set the desktop background color for all users on selected machines, so that the background color reminds them that this is a production server?

Answer (score 2):

The desktop background color may be set by forcing Registry values in GPO.

1. Create new OU and put computer objects in it.
2. Associate a new GPO to the OU.
3. Under Computer Configuration / Policies / Administrative Templates / System / Group Policy, set `User Group Policy loopback processing mode` to Enabled and set Mode to Replace. This will cause the GPO to override any user-specific GPO settings.
4. Set `Turn off Local Group Policy objects` to Enabled. This will enforce the domain-based GPO.
5. In `HKCU/Control Panel/Colors`, set `Background` to the RGB background color.
6. In `HKCU/Control Panel/Desktop`, set `Wallpaper` to empty string.

Run `gpupdate /force`, then logout and login to see the effect.

Comment: Took a bit to find where to enter a registry setting